# Requests/BeautifulSoup throwing error parsing given id

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to parse: id=qualifications in html.

I followed the beautifulsoup documentation, and requests documentation.

My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_content(url):
    if type(url) != str:
        print('You need to included a string')
        exit()
    else:
        req  = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req, 'html.parser')
        qualifications = soup.find(id="qualifications")
        print('Qualifications:\n{}'.format(qualifications))
```

When I run it like:

```
get_content('http://www.somesite.com')
```

it throws an error of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "parse.py", line 10, in get_content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req, 'html.parser')
  File "python3.5/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 176, in __init__
    elif len(markup) <= 256:
TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()
```

How can I make this work? It appears the error might be the size of the resulting request is bigger than 256?

Comment: You'll need to include the *rest* of that traceback. We don't know what error actually is raised.

Comment: Ah, BeautifulSoup doesn't take a `requests` response object, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing in the *response object*, not the actual contents. You'll need to pass in `req.content` instead:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
```

You may want to pass along any encoding information that the server has provided:

```
encoding = req.encoding if 'charset' in req.headers.get('content-type', '').lower() else None
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser', from_encoding=encoding)
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Silly mistake on my end, but i learned something new today :) . Great point about the encoding too!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to let requests rather than beautifulsoup handle the decoding by passing `req.text` instead of `req.content`?  Requests already went to the trouble of decoding the body based on the headers; why make beautifulsoup do it again?

Comment: @jwodder: no, because HTML can contain the codec embedded in a `<meta>` header. The headers on the response are not always (often not) accurate or even present.

Comment: @jwodder: `requests.text` is the decoded content, but because the default codec for `text/*` content type responses is Latin-1 requests will use that to decode to Unicode, which will a) *always* work and b) is often plain wrong and lead to a [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). BeautifulSoup does what browsers do: prefer the `<meta>` header info, or make an educated guess based on character set detection, if not given any other info about the codec used.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'Your url'

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get('https://m.vk.com/uporols_you').text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.